# CSS animation not working in IE, but working in Chrome & Firefox?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-animations

I have a slideshow of 4 images, while page loading animation should fade to left and then to pause.
The following code works in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but not in IE.
Any help would be appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="teaser-large image-loaded">
    <img src="image_01.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS3:

```
@keyframes fadeLeft {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(-3%,0,0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-3%,0,0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(-3%,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(-3%,0,0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.teaser-large {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: fadeLeft 700ms ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeLeft 700ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.image-loaded {
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
   animation-play-state: paused; 
}
```

Comment: Which IE version?

Comment: @Gerard i'm using IE11